# How can I convert html strings to docx readable xml with nodejs?

Tags: html, xml, node.js, docx

I am generating a docx file using nodejs and am inserting strings at various places in the file. I would like to insert some user generated html into the docx but I cannot find any code/library that converts html into docx xml that can be then inserted and parsed correctly.

The html would look something along the lines of:

```
 <p>This is a para <sup> with superscript here </sup></p>
 <p>And a new paragraph here &nbsp</p>
```

I would like to convert this into it's equivalent docx xml string that would keep it's paragraph and superscript styling. It will not be a full html document but just a collection of html tags with content (though they can be wrapped in a containing tag if this is easier). I would prefer to use a well tested library(s) to do it but any code would be a big help! Thanks!

Comment: I understand that unsuitable questions should be voted down but it would be useful to know the reason why, so that I can edit the question appropriately.

Comment: stackoverflow is not the place to ask recommendations about tools, ... but to answer questions related to a specific programming problem

Comment: specific problem - "I would like to convert this [html] into it's equivalent docx xml string that would keep it's paragraph and superscript styling"

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater might do the job well, it is a templating system for docx and pptx.

It doesn't handle the html to docx conversion, but you can embed xml inside your docx using the {@rawXml} syntax.

See here for a demo : http://javascript-ninja.fr/docxtemplater/v1/examples/demo.html#rawxml